# Call delete only if value is a pointer

Tags: c++

I'm making a class that adds some basic operations to an std::map, and I would like to automatically call **delete** after removing an item from the map. But if the second (T2) value isn't a pointer, this can't be done. Is there any way to check?

```
template <class T,class T2>
bool CExtendedMap<T,T2>::remove(T ID)
{
    if(theMap.find(ID)!=theMap.end())
    {
        T2 second = theMap.find(ID)->second;
        theMap.erase(theMap.find(ID));
        //delete second; //Had to comment it out now.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you'd like to behave differently if the value of the paired stored in your `CExtendedMap` is or isn't a pointer.

One easy way of solving the issue is to use template overloads to get the desired effect.

Implement a wrapper function that will use `delete` if the parameter is a pointer, or do nothing if it's not, that's by far the easiest solution.

A sample implementation is provided below:

```
template<class T> inline
void delete_or_nop (T  const&)    {/* NOP */}

template<class T> inline
void delete_or_nop (T* const& p)  {delete p;}
```

---

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int * p = 0;
  int   n = 0;

  delete_or_nop (p);
  delete_or_nop (n);
}
```

Comment: Please use a reference, as copying stuff can be expensive, *especially* if you don't du anything with it.

Answer (score 8):

Use smart pointers instead, that way you don't have to worry about deleting anything. The memory will be freed when you `erase` the element from the map.

Comment: Time to start using boost again then. I picked the other answer though because, you know, it answered the question ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    template<class T>
    class Pointer
    {
        private:
       T* pointer;
       int* ref;


    public:
    Pointer():pointer(0), ref(0)
    {
    （*ref）++;

    }

    Pointer(T* value):pointer(value),reference(0)
    {
    （*ref)++;

    }

    Pointer(const pointer<T>& sp):pointer(sp.pointer),ref(sp.ref)
    {
       (*ref)++;
    }

    ~Pointer()
    {
   if(--(*ref)==0)
     {delete pointer;
       delete ref;
     }
    }
    };
```

There are some operators like ->, *, =  that you need to override.